# nftables Error: syntax error, unexpected saddr

Tags: arp, nftables

I wanted to add the rule `arp saddr ip 192.168.2.1 counter accept` to my Nftables firewall. When reading the config-file with `sudo nft -f /etc/nftables2.conf`, I get the error-message

```
/etc/nftables2.conf:26:21-15: Error: syntax error, unexpected saddr 
                 arp saddr ip 192.168.2.1 counter accept
                                   ^^^^^^
```

Table in question:

```
table arp filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
                arp saddr ip 192.168.2.1 counter accept
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
```

I can´t get it fixed. At first I tried different IPs, then I tried the same with `saddr ether <MAC of device>` instead of the IP address but got the same result.
I use nftables version 0.9.0 on the newest Raspberry Pi OS.
Can someone please point out where my mistake lies? I´m kinda lost..
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @A.B I used the nftables version 0.9.6 from buster-backports and everything worked perfectly. Sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ruleset is correct. But your *nftables* version is slightly too old. Here's the announce including your example:

[[ANNOUNCE] nftables 0.9.1 release](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=156139496810281&w=2):

> Hi!
>
> The Netfilter project proudly presents:
>
> ```
>     nftables 0.9.1
> ```
>
> This release contains fixes and new features, available up with Linux
> kernels >= 5.2.

[...]

> - ARP sender and target IPv4 address matching, eg.
>
>   ```
>     table arp x {
>             chain y {
>                     type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
>                     arp saddr ip 192.168.2.1 counter packets 1 bytes 46
>             }
>     }
>   ```
>
>   this updates rule counters for ARP packets originated from the
>   192.168.2.1 address.

So you might need kernel >= 5.2 (that's unclear if required) but do need nftables >= 0.9.1

For the kernel: https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/ shows that Raspberry Pi OS currently comes with kernel 5.10.x so this is a moot point.

For the *nftables* version, while it's [usually not recommended](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian), you can try and use [*buster-backports*](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) to get a newer version of [*nftables*](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/nftables), currently 0.9.6. If you find this is not suitable for RPi, you should instead recompile from (Debian) sources your own backported package.

Note: the wiki lags a bit and might not always be completely accurate. Usually the man page is more accurate, once the feature exists of course. Eg:

*buster*'s version 0.9.0:

> [ARP HEADER EXPRESSION](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nftables/nft.8#ARP_HEADER_EXPRESSION)
>
> arp [ARP header field]

versus *buster-backports*' version 0.9.6:

> [ARP HEADER EXPRESSION](https://manpages.debian.org/buster-backports/nftables/nft.8#ARP_HEADER_EXPRESSION)
>
> ```
> arp {htype | ptype | hlen | plen | operation | saddr { ip | ether } | daddr { ip | ether }
> ```

---

### Workaround for simple cases (and additional difficulty)

If you really can't change *nftables* for simple cases like this one, it's possible to use a [raw payload expression](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nftables/nft.8#RAW_PAYLOAD_EXPRESSION) instead, with [good knowledge of the ARP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol#Packet_structure), keeping in mind that this protocol is intended to be used on more than just Ethernet and IPv4 and thus has a few generic parts that are always constants in usual IPv4 over Ethernet use (eg: hlen=6, plen=4).

Anyway I cheated and just read back a working ruleset with nftables 0.9.0 to get it displayed as raw payload, and translated the decimal output in hex (except payload offset and length):

```
table arp filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        @nh,112,32 0xc0a80201 counter accept
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

which is easy to read using Wikipedia's link:

- offset 112 (in bits) is offset 14 in bytes: Sender Protocol Address aka `saddr ip`.
- length 32 bits: An IPv4 address length

  0xc0a80201 means 192.168.2.1